# Brunch does not compile bootstrap.css and Javascript compiled files does not run

Tags: brunch

So I want to get my `dist/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css` prepended into my `style.css`. This code below does not work. In debug mode, it states that it doesn't touch `dist/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css` at all.

My second question is, the JS files that I compiled doesn't run. Say I do `console.log`, after compilation, it doesn't get executed. I've seen this post, tried the `autoRequire` config, still doesn't work. It seems that I am putting the wrong path on the `autoRequire` config.

```
module.exports = {
  paths: {
    watched: [
      "./static/javascripts",
      "./static/stylesheets"
    ],

    public: "./public"
  },

  files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: "/javascripts/app.js"
    },

    stylesheets: {
      joinTo: "/stylesheets/app.css"
    }
  },

  modules: {
    autoRequire: {
      '/javascripts/app.js': ['app']
    }
  },

  npm: {
    enabled: true,
    styles: {
      bootstrap: ["dist/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"]
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you try dropping first `/` in the paths?

Comment: @PaulMiller thanks for answering. Which one is it? I tried some combinations and it still didn't work

Comment: One of the issues is that Brunch does not watch `dist` folder. You can add the folder to `paths.watched`, or move the file into a top-level `vendor` directory — either option would work.

Comment: @PaulMiller gotcha! thanks